# find a real number in a form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I solve this problem by assuming the real number is $x$, then I got $m^2+xm-(2x+4)=0$. Then I solve the equation for $m$. This is complicated. Is an easy to find the real number?

> What real number can't be written in the form $$\frac{m^2-4}{2-m}$$ for any value of $m$?

According to the answer sheet, the correct answer is -4

Comment: The fraction is usually $-(2+m)$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
 x&=\frac{m^2-4}{2-m} \\
  &=\frac{(m-2)(m+2)}{2-m} \\
  &= -(m+2) \quad \text{provided} \quad m\neq2 \\
  &\neq -(2+2)
\end{align*}